# Use quotes as value in config file

Tags: c#, config

How do I use quotes as value in config file ? I am using C#

```
 <add key ="LeftParan" value ="""/>
 <add key ="RightParan" value ="""/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.config` files are XML - you need to escape embedded quotes as `&quot;`:

```
<add key ="LeftParan" value ="&quot;"/>
<add key ="RightParan" value ="&quot;"/>
```

Another option is to delimit your attributes with `'` instead of `"` ([thanks Jon Hanna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288174/use-quotes-as-value-in-config-file/12288207#comment16483330_12288207)):

```
<add key ="LeftParan" value ='"'/>
<add key ="RightParan" value ='"'/>
```

Comment: +1. They could also have `value='"'`, which is worth knowing too, but knowing `&quot;` is more important or they'll be stuck when they want to have both `'` and `"` in a value.

Comment: @JonHanna - Didn't consider that option, though it is obvious in retrospect (I probably didn't consider this since all MSDN documentation and the default config values all delimit attributes using `"`)

Comment: I've had using `"` as my consistent XML style since before XML (carrying it over from SGML), so I'd normally go for `&quot;` too. Just thought I'd fill in the gaps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with this caracter `&quot;`

```
<add key ="LeftParan" value ="&quot;"/>
```